# React To Press Of Button On Apple Watch Sprite iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, apple-watch

Here's my question. I would like to have an Apple Watch game react based on the Apple Watch side. But I'm totally new and lost with it.
I think the connectivity between Apple Watch and iOS app is ok, but I don't know how can I catch the event in the Game Controller, and even less how to deal this with Game Scene.
The result of all of my research have just shown characters can move by themselves or by a click event, but nothing about how to bind to any buttons.
So I'm asking for some help regarding this, and if you have any examples, they are welcome.

Here is my viewDidLoad method to load GameScene :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard WCSession.isSupported() else {
        return
    }
    let session = WCSession.default
    session.delegate = self
    session.activate()      
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill                
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true          
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

And my delegate GameController which, I think is supposed to link to the action button with movement logic in GameScene (but maybe I'm wrong on that point):

```
extension GameViewController: WCSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: 
[String : Any]) {   
    //Truly don't know what to put in there 
}
```

And finally my GameScene 'touchesBegan' method, which contains the movement logic:

```
var locx = CGFloat()
var locy = CGFloat()
var character = SKSpriteNode()
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   if(locx > 0) {
       print(locx)
       character.position.x += 1
   } else if (locx < 0) {
       character.position.x -= 1
   }
   if(locy > 0) {
       print(locy)        
       character.position.y += 1
   }else if (locy < 0) {
       character.position.y -= 1
   }
```

}

I'm pretty sure there are some misunderstandings on my side, but I can't find any issues.
Thank for all help you could provide.